# Notice: Undefined index: in 'C:/xampp/htdocs/www/config.php on line 13-opencart 2

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I'm new to opencart and migrate the site from live to localhost,

When i migrated my website server to localhost then admin panel working properly but error in front end...

When i click on register tab or any product getting error object not found and product images not display banner also not display,link override path like "http://localhost/www/C:/xampp/htdocs/www/index.php?route=account/register" and also config.php line 13 error i will show you the line 13 code below,

```
$path = str_replace("index.php","",str_replace($root, "", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));
```

i didnit get what is file name i will put inside "$_server['']"

please help me.

Comment: Notice is not an error. It won't crash the script but maybe a function cannot run properly. Almost every websites has Notice but they hide it. You can put `error_reporting(E_ERROR|E_WARNING);` in the main php (or every PHP needs to load the file before itself). This notice will be gone.

Comment: My link when i click on register and its show blank page..http://localhost/www/C:/xampp/htdocs/www/index.php?route=account/register